# Iterating through map and checking if key is present in another map

Tags: java, jsp, el

I'm iterating through my map:

I put my map in the controller model attribute like:

```
model.addAttribute("myMap", realMapObject);
```

JSP Code:

```
<c:forEach items="${myMap}" var="entry">
..... works perfectly iteration itself
.....
```

And I need to check if `myMap` entry key is present in another map (`anotherMap`). I tried this :

```
model.addAttribute("anotherMap", realMapObjectAnotherMap);
```

JSP Code:

```
<c:forEach items="${myMap}" var="entry">
    .....
    .....works perfectly 
 <c:choose>
 <c:when test="${not empty ${anotherMap['${entry.key}']}}">
        <h2>${entry.key} - YES</h2>
 </c:when>

 <c:otherwise>
        <h2>${entry.key} - NOT</h2>
 </c:otherwise>
 </c:choose>
```

I'm getting this error:

> contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't nest EL expressions like `${ ${ } }`. You need to do it in the same single EL expression.

```html
<c:when test="${not empty anotherMap[entry.key]}">
```

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)
- [Java EE 6 tutorial - Examples of EL expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaim.html)